# JPA persist becomes slower and slower

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many, persist

This scenario uses a simple oneToMany relationship with cascade persist on both directions.

**Many:**

```
@javax.persistence.Entity(name="Many")
public class Many {
    @javax.persistence.ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    protected One one;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long primaryKey;

    public void setM(One one) {
        this.one = one;
        // comment out this line and performance becomes stable
        this.one.getMany().add(this);
    }

    // other setters, getters, etc...
}
```

**One:**

```
@javax.persistence.Entity(name="One")
public class One {
    @javax.persistence.OneToMany(mappedBy="m", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    protected java.util.Set<Many> many = com.google.common.collect.Sets.newHashSet();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long primaryKey;

    private String name;

    // setters, getters, etc... 
}
```

**Test:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test-pu");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sw.reset();
            sw.start();
            persistMVs(emf, em);
            System.err.println("Elapsed: " + sw.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + " ms");
        }

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}

private static void persistMVs(EntityManagerFactory emf, EntityManager em) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    One one = getOrCreateOne(em);

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        Many many = new Many();
        many.setM(one);
        em.persist(many);
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The test is an endless loop which tries to insert 20000 `Many` entities associated with a single `One` entity. Each loop begins with the creation of a new `EntityManagerFactory` to show the negative performance effect of the increasing database.

The expected behavior would be that, the insertion time of the entities does not increase drastically, however after each **WHILE CYCLE** there is an order of magnitude increase.

**Notes:**

- I have tried eclipseLink, Hibernate, OpenJPA and all suffered from this kind of slowdown.
- If I don't update the Many collection of One, then there is no degradation (see the commented line of Many).
- **If I don't create a new EntityManagerFactory, then there is no degradation even after half a million entities.**
- The slow part is `em.persist(many);` (I measured it).
- Check out https://github.com/kupsef/OneToMany and start the test with
  `gradle start`.

Why would the initial size of the database matter in this case? Should I consider this behavior as a bug?

Comment: why don't you look at the log and understand it?

Comment: What logs would you suggest? The sql logs only differ at the first cycle (of the inner for), it additionally contains the fetching of the Many entities. This does not explain the degradation as the succeeding cycles don't fetch them (most probably because they got cached for later use, as expected).

Comment: the logs of the JPA implementation you use. The implementation I use (DataNucleus) always shows lots of info to track down potential problems so I assume others are equally useful

Comment: The only log entry emitted by the persist operation is just a note that persist was called. Nothing useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to expand on Predrag's answer - traversing a 1:M relationship not only has the cost of bringing in the entities and any expands the object graph, but those entities remain managed within the persistent unit.  Because your test is reusing the same EntityManager for repeated transactions, the cache of managed entities continues to grow with each iteration.  This cache of managed entities must be traversed and checked for changes every time the context is synchronized with the database - this occurs on flush, transaction commit or even queries.

If you must bring in large object graphs, what can be done to mitigate this is either release and obtain new EntityManagers for each transactional boundary, or occasionally flush and clear the EntityManager.  Either option allows it to release some of the managed entities, so it does not need to check them all for changes on each commit.

Edit>
Your "Many" class has overriden the hashCode method and is building its hashcode using the hashcode of its referenced "One" with its primary key.  This causes each and every "Many" you persist in your loops to have the same hashcode, as GenerationType.IDENTITY can only assign sequences when the insert statement occurs - which happens during synchronization (flush/commit).  This method might be causing cache lookups, which occur while the provider traverses the growing object model on each persist call due to the cascade persist call, to take longer and longer.

Comment: The size of the cache grows, I know that, but without the recreation of the EMF, there is no performance degradation, and even in that case all the entities will be managed and present in the cache. Also note that the inner for cycles take the same time within a while loop, but drastically increases after each while iteration.

Comment: Try to remove the cascade persist options on your relationships so the persist doesn't have to cascade through the growing object model, but I'm not sure I understood your statement.  The EM has its own cache that grows, and every object you pass into persist must be checked against it.  You've also overriden the equals and hashcode - try removing your implementation and see if that is affecting your results.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was with equals/hashCode, but not in the way you would expect:) Without them the insertion time increases after each inner for cycle (which was constant within a while cycle). So the badly implemented equals/hashCode somehow hid the degradation temporary.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in `this.one.getMany()`, because in each iteration more and more entities need to be loaded from this relationship.

`@OneToMany` relation is lazy by default, so when you call `getMany()` JPA provider has to initialize every entity form the collection, which takes more time as the size of it grows.

If you don't create a new `EntityManagerFactory` in each iteration, the entities from the last iteration remain in cache so a lot less queries are executed.

Comment: Then I would expect a single delay at the first call to getMany() to populate the cache, but it remains slow through all the entities (all the 20000 Many).

Comment: I checked it, and only the first call to getMany() fetches the entries:/